# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy' copy: Invalid argument - ffmpeg Error

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I'm trying to get the video and first voice channel with converted AAC. Also trying to add a subtitle.

The command I've used is:

`ffmpeg -i yourmkv.mkv -i yoursubtitles.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -c:v copy -c:a:0 aac copy -c:s copy youroutput.mkv`

But it gives an error. Without adding a subtitle, I can make it work with using this command:

`ffmpeg -i inputfile.mkv -c:v copy -c:a:0 aac outputfile.mkv`

But how should I add a subtitle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error in here: `-c:a:0 aac copy`; you cannot specify to both copy and convert a stream.

That should work:

```
ffmpeg -i yourmkv.mkv -i yoursubtitles.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -c:v copy -c:a:0 aac -c:s copy youroutput.mkv
```